# Android SQLite database seems to clear every time i open a new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I've been trying to fix these two bugs for a while and I feel like it has to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of what happens when I open up a new activity. Basically the program is a task management program. It works fine when I add new tasks without modifying the category, and the database updates fine and the main page of the application updates as I add new tasks to display these new tasks.

However, I recently added functionality for an "add categories" button. The purpose of this button is to open up a new listactivity that allows users to add new categories of tasks. Every time I open this from the task editing activity and then press the back button to get back to the main page, all of the tasks in the database get cleared. Wondering if anyone can tell me what's going on and why the data is getting wiped out.

here's the relevant code snippet from the front page (the list view showing all of the tasks:

```
private RemindersDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);
    mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}


private void fillData() {
    Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(reminders);
}
```

Here's some of the code for my task editing view (the one calling the activity for the category listing):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
    //mCatDbHelper = new CategoriesDbAdapter(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);

    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    //mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);
    mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
    mLowPriorityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.low_priority);
    mMedPriorityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.med_priority);
    mHighPriorityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.high_priority);
    mManageCategories = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manage_categories);
    mSchoolRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_schoolwork);
    mFamilyRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_family);
    mOtherRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_other);
    mContext = this;

    priority = "Low";
    category = "Other";


    mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                    : -1L;


    registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
}

private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
    if (mRowId == -1L) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                : -1L;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mDbHelper.close(); 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDbHelper.open(); 
    setRowIdFromIntent();

    //if(mRowId != -1L)
    populateFields();
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG: 
            return showDatePicker();
        case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG: 
            return showTimePicker(); 
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

private void populateFields()  {



    // Only populate the text boxes and change the calendar date
    // if the row is not null from the database. 
    if (mRowId != -1L) {
        Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(reminder);
        mTitleText.setText(reminder.getString(
                reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
       category = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY));
       if(category.equals("School"))
           mSchoolRadio.setChecked(true);
       else if(category.equals("Family"))
           mFamilyRadio.setChecked(true);
       else
           mOtherRadio.setChecked(true);



        // Get the date from the database and format it for our use. 
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            String dateString = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME)); 
            date = dateTimeFormat.parse(dateString);
            mCalendar.setTime(date); 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("ReminderEditActivity", e.getMessage(), e); 
        } 
    } else {
        // This is a new task - add defaults from preferences if set. 
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
        String defaultTitleKey = getString(R.string.pref_task_title_key); 
        String defaultTimeKey = getString(R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key); 

        String defaultTitle = prefs.getString(defaultTitleKey, null);
        String defaultTime = prefs.getString(defaultTimeKey, null); 

        if(defaultTitle != null)
            mTitleText.setText(defaultTitle); 

        if(defaultTime != null)
            mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(defaultTime));

    }

    updateDateButtonText(); 
    updateTimeButtonText(); 

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(mRowId == -1L)
        mRowId = -1L;
    outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

/*
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                : -1L;
}
*/

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    //String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT); 
    String reminderDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    if (mRowId == -1L) {

        long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title, priority, category, reminderDateTime);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
       mDbHelper.updateReminder(mRowId, title, priority, category, reminderDateTime);
    }

    new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mRowId, mCalendar); 
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Here's the call (in the same class as the above code) to the new CategoryListActivity activity that's causing the problems:

```
mManageCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, CategoryListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            //populateFields();
        }
    });
```

I left out a lot of the less relevant code. Anyway like I said above... the main problem is that as soon as I start this new CategoryListActivity activity, the database and all the tasks get wiped out. weirdly, even if I restart the emulator the tasks don't get wiped as long as I don't start the CategoryListActivity. If anyone has any idea what's going on please help.

Comment: The interesting code is in `RemindersDbAdapter`, please post that.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew checkout this two links that will explain you everything about database integration.
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Thanks I just checked them out, but I don't see anything on those two sites about why my database keeps getting cleared when I open up a new activity?

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE. i commented out the lines in the CategoryListActivity class where I initialize a new database adapter and suddenly the database doesn't get cleared anymore. I currently have two different database adapter classes (one for tasks, and one for categories). Am i only allowed to have one type of database adapter class?